# AJAX ReorderList breaking in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, reorderlist

Ok guys/girls I have an issue with a AJAX ReorderList and Chrome (yes, I know chrome is buggy).

When trying to reorder any of the items as I click to start a drag the browser starts scrolling upwards and the item in which I'm trying to drag is well off the cursor however I cannot reproduce this in firefox or IE7/8/9.

```
<act:ReorderList id="rolPages" runat="server"
     DragHandleAlignment="Left"
     PostBackOnReorder="true"
     Width="100%"
     DataKeyField="Id"
     SortOrderField="SortOrder"
     CallbackCssStyle="callbackStyle"
     OnItemReorder="rolPages_ItemReorder"
     OnItemDataBound="rolPages_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="itemArea">
             <b><asp:Label ID="lblSortOrder" runat="server" /></b>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <asp:Label ID="lblMenuText" runat="server" />
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <ReorderTemplate>
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="reorderCue" />
     </ReorderTemplate>
     <DragHandleTemplate>
        <div class="dragHandle"></div>
     </DragHandleTemplate>
 </act:ReorderList>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok nevermind I have resolved this issue(just a matter of getting the new release of the toolkit.

Comment: So make this as answer and accept it - or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind I have resolved this issue(just a matter of getting the new release of the toolkit.